# How can I create a new answer mode?

Tags: javascript, php, css, arrays, dom

I want to create a quiz app, but with a catch, each questions from my bank of question must be random and at least one question must use radio buttons to answer, at least one question should use a drop down and at least one should use a text input from the 5 questions to be asked. I already created a drop down in my html file, how do I create the two other types of answer mode ?

```js
const userName = document.getElementById("user-name");
const submitUserName = document.getElementById("submitUserName");
const nav = document.querySelector("a");

submitUserName.onclick = function() {
    
    if (userName.value == "") {
        alert("Kindly Input your Name !")
    } else {
        nav.setAttribute("href", "/quiz/index.html")
    }
}

const quizQuestions = [
    {
        question: "Which language runs in a web browser ?",
        a: "Python",
        b: "Javascript",
        c: "Java",
        d: "Flutter",
        ans: b, 
    },

    {
        question: "How many standard color names does HTML supports ?",
        a: "20",
        b: "90",
        c: "140",
        d: "125",
        ans: c, 
    },

    {
        question: "Javascript displays numbers as base ?",
        a: "10",
        b: "2",
        c: "5",
        d: "12",
        ans: a, 
    },

    {
        question: "Who is the father of computer ?",
        a: "Charles Babbage",
        b: "Allan Turing",
        c: "Issac Newton",
        d: "Bill Gate",
        ans: a, 
    },

    {
        question: "The brain of a computer is ?",
        a: "ALU",
        b: "DVD",
        c: "CPU",
        d: "Memory",
        ans: c, 
    },

    {
        question: "What year was JavaScript launched ?",
        a: "1996",
        b: "1995",
        c: "1994",
        d: "1993",
        ans: b, 
    },

    {
        question: "Junk e-mail is called ?",
        a: "junk",
        b: "spoof",
        c: "sperm",
        d: "spam",
        ans: d, 
    },

    {
        question: "Which tag is used for list-items ?",
        a: "<ol>",
        b: "<ul>",
        c: "<dl>",
        d: "<li>",
        ans: d, 
    },

    {
        question: "How old is Bill Gate ?",
        a: "59",
        b: "60",
        c: "56",
        d: "66",
        ans: d, 
    },
];
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,300,regular,500,600,700,800,900);
:root {
    --background: rgb(29, 26, 26);
    --text-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h3, h4 {
    color: var(--text-color);
}

body {
    background-color: var(--background);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.quiz-container {
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 70%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 35px;
}

.header h3 {
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-size: 30px;
}

.questions {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 20px;
}

.question-no {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.question-options {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 25px;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

select {
    padding: 8px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

option{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.question-tog {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

button {
    padding: 8px 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 20px;
}

i {
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Interactive Quiz App</title>
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.2/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/quiz/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Quiz Container -->
    <div class="quiz-container">
        <div class="header"><h3>Interactive Quiz App</h3></div>

        <div class="quiz">
            <div class="question-no"><h3>Question 1 of 5</h3></div>

            <div class="questions">
                <div class="question-text">
                    <h4 id="question">When is 2 * 18 ?</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="question-options">
                        <select name="format" id="format">
                            <option selected disabled>Choose your answer</option>
                            <option value="1">32</option>
                            <option value="2">36</option>
                            <option value="3">62</option>
                            <option value="4">22</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Question Next and Previous -->
        <div class="question-tog">
            <button class="prev"> <span>Prev</span> <i class='bx bx-left-arrow-alt'></i></button>
            <button class="next"> <span>Next</span> <i class='bx bx-right-arrow-alt'></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="/quiz/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a pretty big and general question for this place. I will point out, however, that if you put all the questions and answers in your javascript it will be really easy to cheat.

Comment: Generally: design the interface in HTML and CSS, then use JS to recreate it using DOM